# How do I post an XML code sample?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, code-formatting

I'm trying to ask a question about XML and would like to include a sample document so that my question is clear. Before I can ask my question, I need to figure out how to type xml in here and and have it displayed. I've tried every combination of pre, blink, quotes slashes... and looked through the formatting help but haven't had any luck. How can I display my XML in a stackoverflow question?

Comment: This belongs over on [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).  (Short answer: indent each line with four spaces.)

Comment: I'm sorry, this isn't making sense to me. I'll start with trying to get "<document>" to show up in a pre block. I've put 4 spaces everywhere I can think of, with no success...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See at the top  of [**the editing help**](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) (highlight by me):

> ### Code and Preformatted Text
>
> **Indent four spaces** to create an escaped `<pre><code>` block:
>
> ```
> printf("goodbye world!");  /* his suicide note
>                               was in C */
> ```
>
> The text will be wrapped in tags, and displayed in a monospaced font. The first four spaces will be stripped off, but all other whitespace will be preserved.
>
> Markdown and HTML is ignored within a code block:
>
> ```
> <blink>
>    You would hate this if it weren't
>    wrapped in a code block.
> </blink>
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Use code formatting (four leading spaces)

```
<this>
  <type="xml">is xml</type>
</this>
```